# Topological Quantum Field Theory: Compact Implies Finite Boundaries

Tags: general-topology, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, cobordism, topological-quantum-field-theory

The following is from [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/lee/lee.pdf) paper.

> A bordism $B:\coprod_{i\in I} S^1 \to \coprod_{j\in J} S^1$ is just a
>   “generalized pair of pants” - a pair of pants with one waist hole for
>   each $i\in I$ and one leg hole for each $j\in J$ Since both $I$ and
>   $J$ are finite sets, as required by compactness....

I assume the author is using the general topology version of compactness, i.e., the existence of a finite subcover.  However, I don't see how to apply compactness to get the finiteness of $i$ and $j$ conclusion.  What is the open cover and what is the finite subcover in this case?  The result seems to imply that the disjoint union of $S^1$ is the finite subcover but I can't seem to make this precise.

EDIT:  This is actually fairly simple, not sure what I was thinking.  Basically if $i,j$ aren't finite then compactness would be violated.

Comment: If a manifold is compact, every infinite subset has a accumulation point. An infinite disjoint union of circles is not compact , since you can choose one point from each circle, and that set has no accumulation points. You want to start with something less heady. Try this: http://mat.uab.es/~kock/TQFT/FS.pdf

Comment: May I ask you why you reject my edit and roll back? Thanks

Comment: @Andrews So if I understand correctly the edit was to remove the general topology tag.  IMHO this question, although fairly basic, had a lot to do with general topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X=\coprod_{i\in I} S_i$ (where each $S_i$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$) with $I$ infinite. An open cover of $X$ is $C=\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$. For any finite subset $D\subset C$ there is some $i\in I$ such that $S_i\not\in D$ and thus $D$ can't be a subcover. We have found a cover $C$ without finite subcover, and thus $X$ isn't compact.